# SSRS Report Insert External files into final pdf report

Tags: reporting-services

It's an ERP application, job traveller report in pdf, one page per operation. 
Each operation can have associated drawings, usually one but it can be two or three or even none. Drawing IDs are referenced in a dwgs field for each operation and drawings which are single page pdfs are available to the server.

Now we need to generate SSRS report inserting each operation's drawings after the operation page so we get a single multi page pdf with operations and drawings together.
Resulting pdf may look like the following:

```
Operation 1
Drawing 1.1
Operation 2
Drawing 2.1
Drawing 2.2
etc...
```

Looking for some leads how to do this if possible.

Thanks

Comment: You can get your result by storing all pdf drawing into image format. If the images are stored in db server it is very easy to embed in report. Otherwise you can write the formula to show image drawing in report.

Comment: using soundappan As suggestion you can create a tabix which groups per operation and has a group header of the size of a page containing the operation content, and detail rows of a page size containing the images